# Use pandas.apply with multiple arguments to return several columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to preprocess a dataset with pandas. I want to use a function with multiple arguments (one from a column of the dataframe, others are variables) which returns several outputs like this:

```
def preprocess(Series,var1,var2,var3,var4):
   return 1,2,3,4
```

I want to use the native pandas.apply to use this function on one column of my dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])

df['C'], df['D'], df['E'], df['F'] = df.apply(lambda x: preprocess(x['A'], 1, 2, 3, 4), axis=1)
```

But the last line gives me the following error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

I understand my last line returns one tuple of 4 values `(1,2,3,4)` per line whereas I wanted to get each of these values in the columns `C`, `D`, etc.

How can I perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-write your function to return a series, that way, `apply` returns a dataframe:

```
def preprocess(Series,var1,var2,var3,var4):
    return pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
```

Then your code would run and return

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  4  9  0  1  2  3
1  4  9  0  1  2  3
2  4  9  0  1  2  3
```

**Update**: Without rewrite of the function:

```
processed = df.apply(lambda x: preprocess(x['A'], 1, 2, 3, 4), axis=1)
df['C'], df['D'], df['E'], df['F'] = np.array(processed.to_list()).T
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a way to avoid re-write my function? I have other data from json file where the function preprocess is already working. I would prefer to generalize my preprocessing with one function.